# How to change current line color in debugging mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I'm trying to change the color of a current line in a debugging mode.

So, I know how to change color in general, but don't know what is the name of the parameter.

for example, to change a selected line we need **"editor.lineHighlightBackground"**

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Base16 Dark Oceanic Next]": {
      "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#ff0000",
    }
  }
```

but, how to change the line color which appears during debugging?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change current break line color in debugging mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990016/how-to-change-current-break-line-color-in-debugging-mode)

Answer (score 12):

Write the customization without "[Base16 Dark Oceanic Next]" as :

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#ff0000",
}
```

Comment: This changes the color of the currently selected line. How do you change the color of the currently active line **while debugging**?

Comment: It's answered in the other duplicate: To change the color of the currently active line **while debugging** change `editor.stackFrameHighlightBackground`.

Comment: That's why I hate .json being used for this kind of stuff: you cannot add a comment to clarify what that friggn string means !
Would be better the the developers of vsc had writtent these properties in a meaningful way. 
There, my rant of the day.

Comment: @kamikater I dug through 6+ posts before finding your obscure comment, this is the solution was looking for and believe it would make a worthy answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#debug-colors. The colour customization points you are looking for are

- `editor.stackFrameHighlightBackground`: "*Background color of the top stack frame highlight in the editor.*"
- `editor.focusedStackFrameHighlightBackground`: "*Background color of the focused stack frame highlight in the editor.*"

While you're at it, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#debug-icons-colors. You might also be interested in colour customization points for the glyph margin decorations / debug icons:

- `debugIcon.breakpointCurrentStackframeForeground`: "*Icon color for the current breakpoint stack frame.*"
- `debugIcon.breakpointStackframeForeground`: "*Icon color for all breakpoint stack frames.*"

Answer (score 1):

If `editor.lineHighlightBackground` doesn't do what you want, try `editor.stackFrameHighlightBackground`.