# How do I set the highlight color for current position line in debug mode in a dark theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I'm using a theme Dark+.

In debug mode, the highlight color from the debugging position is very unsuccessful - nothing is visible. I went through almost all the parameters on this [Theme Color Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference), but not one did not fit.

Question: what parameter changes this unfit yellow color?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't think you can, here is another recent question that went unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262762/how-to-change-current-line-color-in-debugging-mode

Answer (score 5):

Can be configured by editing settings.json file of Visual Studio Code.
Read more on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "debugToolBar.background": "#004275",
    "editor.stackFrameHighlightBackground": "#004275", // current active debug line
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 1):

Accidentally saw that we code is written on html + javascript

So, I climbed in the bowels and found how to overcome the problem with dirty hack.

For windows
Open file:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\
>   workbench.main.css

And add to the end of the file:

> .debug-remove-token-colors{background-color: #4b4b18 !important;
>   border: 1px solid #4b4b18 !important;}

OR

> .debug-remove-token-colors {background-color: #000 !important;
>   border-top: 1px solid #4b4b18 !important; border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4b18 !important;}

Where the color really changes - I never found it. Although the problem is solved. Although VScode swore that his files had changed.