# How to change current break line color in debugging mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am asking specifically for VSCode and not VS Studio - because there everything is totally simple.

How to change current break line color in debugging mode - i.e the line where the code execution stopped due to e.g. a breakpoint or singlestep action?

Currently this line is shown with a light yellow background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#debug), I found something that might help you:

## **Debug**

- `debugToolBar.background`: Debug toolbar background color.
- `debugToolBar.border`: Debug toolbar border color.
- `editor.stackFrameHighlightBackground`: Background color of the top stack frame highlight in the editor.
- `editor.focusedStackFrameHighlightBackground`: Background color of the focused stack frame highlight in the editor.

I think one of the last two is what you're looking for.

Hope it helps.